# how to print full page Jtable

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, printing, jtable

I want to print my Jtable so I i used the table.print() method :)

The method works fine and my printer to :)

But I'm getting this:

[image: my jtable]

So as you can see I'm getting very small table on my a4 page...

I want it to be readable and much more large then this..

here is my code:

```
MessageFormat header = new MessageFormat("- {0} -"); 
                try {
                    AllEmployeesTablePanel.getEmps().print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH,header,null);
                } catch (java.awt.print.PrinterException e1) {
                     System.err.format("Cannot print %s%n", e1.getMessage()); 
                }
```

what should I do?

Comment: This is merely a thought, but is there no alternative for testing print format (Ex.: Word document) rather than actually printing it? Because that can lead to a lot of wasted paper!

Answer (score 1):

please check your code or your printer setting go to this  [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/printtable.html).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it! There had been an issue with my printer settings.

Answer (score 0):

change like this

```
MessageFormat header=new MessageFormat("Report Print");
MessageFormat footer=new MessageFormat("page{0,number,integer}");

try {
    jTable3.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH,header,footer);    
} catch(java.awt.print.PrinterException e) {
    System.err.format("cant print %s%n",e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Hi chinna 98, welcome to Stackoverflow! Yo'll want to add a little bit of a description to your answer to help clarify a little of what is going on in your solution. This helps the OP and future readers understand.